# how to pass APEX URL with parameters?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have this URL how can I pass it in oracle apex ,

I tried alot but its open the URL with the name of page item

this is the URL

```
http://ZERO/?user=epr&password=epr&PatientID=:P6_PATIENT_NO&AccessionNumber=:P6_IMAGE_NO
```

I need to pass 2 parameters from the page :

```
:P6_PATIENT_NO
:P6_IMAGE_NO
```

How can I pass the selected value when click the link ?

I found this link how to use URL parameters how can I do it with my case ?

```
https://www.tech-spy.co.uk/2018/09/oracle-apex-url-parameters-and-construction/
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand how you're creating that URL, but - from Apex point of view - you should utilize APEX_PAGE.GET_URL function. For example:

```
SELECT apex_page.get_url (p_page    => 2,
                          p_items   => 'P2_PATIENT_NO,P2_IMAGE_NO',
                          p_values  => :P6_PATIENT_NO || ',' || :P6_IMAGE_NO) f_url
  FROM DUAL;
```

It would return valid URL which can be used for navigation to another page (`2`, in my example).

Have a look at documentation related to it, e.g. [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/22.1/aeapi/GET_URL-Function.html#GUID-83A2A2A0-5B43-4A3E-BBD3-2FBD3B7B01CE).

Comment: I need to pass 2 parameters to another software this is the URL for the other software its Radiology imaging system I need to send patient medical record number and image number now the URL opened but in the other software its not passing the value its passing the page item name   :P_PATIENT_NO and :P_IMAGE_NO instead of selected row patient no and image no , how to pass the value not the page item name , I created link of type URL and put this URL in it .

Comment: Aha. Then it depends on a way you're creating the URL. Is it stored in a local variable, in a page item, or ...? How did you create it? Could you share that piece of code?

Comment: I saved the link in a PATIENT_NO page item , when click patient no row it will pass it to the other software and open radiology image there is integration between 2 software and can open the image when pass patient no and image no thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using the following URL :

```
javascript:window.open('http://ZERO/?user=epr&password=epr&PatientID=#PATIENT_NO#&AccessionNumber=#IMAGE_NO#')
```

I created a link on PATIENT_NO column and used this URL and send
#PATIENT_NO , #IMAGE_NO# for selected row to other software which open image for this patient

About the URL I didn't create it I got it from other software developer they requested to send this information to other software to see radiology image from that software and I paste it as the link when click PATIENT_NO page item it will redirect to URL and search for patient image in the other software